# SharePoint Logo URL, pointing to wrong page

Tags: url, site

The logo on my sharepoint site is pointing to a page that no longer exists and I have no idea how to fix it! HELP!!

Comment: I just realized as well, that depending on where I am on the site it sends me to a different place.

Comment: Could you give us the url of the page where you are and the url where the logo is pointing?

Comment: Of course, so I've put the welcome page as /teams/WaterOps/SharepointOperationsManual/Pages/Home.aspx so that is what it should be linked to. Clicking the link from any pages on the site such as /teams/WaterOps/SharepointOperationsManual/Lists/PSLS%20Datesheet/AllItems.aspx sends me to a combination of different places, /teams/WaterOps/SharepointOperationsManual/Pages/Under%20Construction.aspx, sometimes it sends me to the correct location thought. But most times it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the page you want to be your home page. In the ribbon, go to the Page tab and click `Make Homepage`. This will reset the logo image to go to the desired page.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that, and it isn't working.